# mpiexec hangs for remote execution

Tags: amazon-ec2, mpi, openmpi

I have two EC2 instances.

1. Ubuntu 12.04 running OpenMPI 1.4.3
2. Ubuntu 14.04 running OpenMPI 1.6.5

I run this command:

```
mpiexec --hostfile machines ls
```

where "machines" is a file that contains the IP address of the other server that the command is being run on.  Every time, it hangs indefinitely.  When I replace the IP address with the server that the command is being run on, it works fine.  I can password-less ssh between machines fine.

I tried having the same version of MPI on both machines, but could not get that to work.  apt-get installs different versions on both machines for some reason.

What can I do to make MPI work between machines?

Comment: Do you have host-specific configurations in your `~/.ssh/config` file (on the host where the `mpiexec` command is being executed)?

Comment: Nope.  I don't have a .ssh/config file.  Do I need one?

Comment: I think I found what the problem is.  I ran the command with the debug option -d and found this error:

 > ORTE_ERROR_LOG: Data unpack had inadequate space in file base/odls_base_default_fns.c at line 528 
> ORTE_ERROR_LOG: Data unpack had inadequate space in file orted/orted_comm.c at line 292 

I googled this error and came across this site http://www.open-mpi.org/community/lists/users/2013/06/22189.php.  It says that I need to have the same version of MPI installed on both machines.  Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: You can compile and install a certain Open MPI version on both nodes and either pass `mpiexec` the `--prefix /path/to/install` option or call it by its full path, e.g. `/path/to/install/bin/mpiexec`.